# Insert data from android app to PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I got some problem with sending data from an android app to MySQL database through PHP. the problem is that data is received but not inserted to the database. here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("db_config.php");

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registeration(id,name,number,password) VALUES('','$name','$number','$password')");    

if ($result > 0) {
   $response["success"] = 1;
}    
else {
   $response["success"] = 0;
}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

- Check your spelling. Is your table really named `registeration`
- Remove the primary key in the SQL statement. It is most probably an int, you pass a varchar.
- Do not use mysql_*. Use PDO or mysqli_* with prepared statements
- Do not store passwords as plain text, but use PHP's password feature (my personal 2 cents)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are inserting `null` value in your primary key. Change your query with this :

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registeration(name,number,password) VALUES('$name','$number','$password')");
```

> Two important thing :
>
> 1) Dont use `mysql_*`. It's removed from PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*` or
>   `PDO`.
>
> 2) Your query is open for sql injection. See this : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thanks, I edited the code but the same problem, the result is still null and $response["success"] is also 0

Comment: Did you check for spell mistake `registeration`. Is it correct table?